# joining several tables with inner and outer.

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I'm trying to combine inner and outer join but can't get it to work. I have a total of 7 tables that needs to be joined together in one query. 
First I only had 6 and had no problem as everything was inner joins. But now I've added a seventh table and can't get it right. I think I need to use OUTER JOIN somehow but don't know how. 
I will only use 3 tables in this example because I think that I can manage to fix the rest if you help me get started.

List of my tables:

Table1=dbo.kala (This is the 7th table i added.

Table2=dbo.ti

Table3=dbo.ao

```
SELECT kala.kaldat
From dbo.kala
Where kala.kaldat Between '170407' AND '170410'
```

The above query returns the following result.

```
Result1
|kaldat    |
|2017-04-07|
|2017-04-08|
|2017-04-09|
|2017-04-10|
```

.

```
SELECT ti.startdat, ti.artnr, ti.aonr, ti.aopos, ao.prodgr
From dbo.ti
INNER JOIN dbo.ao ON ti.aonr = ao.aonr AND ti.aopos = ao.aopos
Where ti.startdat Between '170407' AND '170410'
```

The above query returns the following result.

```
Result2
ti.startdat| ti.artnr| ti.aonr|ti.aopos|ao.prodgr|
2017-04-07 | 123     | 0001   |10      |50       |
2017-04-10 | 456     | 0002   |20      |60       |
```

The result I want is this (3).

```
Result3
kala.kaldat| ti.artnr| ti.aonr|ti.aopos|ao.prodgr|
2017-04-07 | 123     | 0001   |10      |50       |
2017-04-08 |         |        |        |         |
2017-04-09 |         |        |        |         |
2017-04-10 | 456     | 0002   |20      |60       |
```

The join between dbo.kala and dbo.ti is on kala.kaldat = ti.startdat.

Hopefully you guys understand what I'm trying to get through here. If not i apologize beforehand and will gladly try to explain better. Thanks in advance!

*Note the remaining 4 tables that aren't in this example needs to be joined (INNER?) with dbo.ti.

Comment: Left join is what you're after but if you have any where clause criteria that involves the table on the "right" of the "Left" join, then it needs to be put on the join or your left join simulates a inner join.

Comment: you are trying to select data that have no index in one of the 3 tables, for that you need to use left join or full outer join depending in what you want to get ---> see https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zgg.png

Comment: I do actually have more where clauses that are connected to to dbo.ti... All I need from dbo.kala is the list of dates. Then I want the rest of the tables to just fill in the information on the correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select dates from `kala`, then outer join `ti`, then outer join `ao`.

```
SELECT kala.kaldat, ti.artnr, ti.aonr, ti.aopos, ao.prodgr
FROM dbo.kala
LEFT JOIN dbo.ti ON kala.kaldat = ti.startdat
LEFT JOIN dbo.ao ON ti.aonr = ao.aonr AND ti.aopos = ao.aopos
WHERE kala.kaldat BETWEEN '20170407' AND '20170410';
```

(You must outer join `ao`, too, because if the `ti` record is outer-joined, then its `aonr` and `aopos` are null. If you inner joined `ao`, you'd get no match and thus discard the row from your results.)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN dbo.ao ON ti.aonr = ao.aonr AND ti.aopos = ao.aopos`

What you want to achieve requires using

`LEFT JOIN dbo.ao ON ti.aonr = ao.aonr AND ti.aopos = ao.aopos`

Comment: Thank you but you have not used table "kala" at all?

Comment: Well, you can add these tables yourself adding another JOIN to the query. You just add another join:

`LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id`

So on, so on.